# CSS not rendering in Django

Tags: python, django, oop

I am trying to use a css stylesheet and I have followed https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial06/ tutorial to the end to setup my css files. Still they are not rendering when I am running it on localhost.

This is my project structure:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCvQA.png)

And this is the code I am currently using:

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'pwash/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'pwash/css/datepicker3.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'pwash/css/bootstrap-table.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'pwash/css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Icons-->
<script src="{% static 'pwash/js/lumino.glyphs.js' %}"></script>
```

I have added my app in setting.py file. I have followed the norms.

Comment: have you done the obvious things like checking the generated HTML? Looking at the developer console for 404?

Comment: Yes. Html is generated. In the developer console css is not showing any 404 error. Although the style editor in the console is showing this message:  <p>
      You're seeing this error because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in
      your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>, and Django
      will display a standard 404 page.
    </p>

Comment: But that is a standard html and is displayed when there is some error. Which is not being showed during the loading of the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not followed the tutorial. For some reason you have put your static files inside your template directory; that's not where they belong. They need to be in a static directory, directly inside the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't see that at all. It worked. I guess I needed a extra pair of eyes. @DanielRoseMan :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove static folder in templates in put it on root tree e.g.:pwash/static or setting it in your settings.
Something like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/pwash/static')
```

)
With a little care on which os you use...In Windows is \ instead of / in linux.